# Windows 7: Uninstall multiple programs

Tags: windows, uninstall

I am looking for a program that can automatically uninstall multiple programs one right after the other.

For my job, I initialize, set up, and remove junkware from computers for new employees. The first 2 I have down pretty fast and easy, but the last one takes a long time. I have to go in and manually remove about 15 applications/programs that come on the new computers that the new employees don't need. It takes a long time to remove all of them individually.

It would be nice if I could just select all the programs I want to uninstall and have a program do it automatically without me needing to be there to to select the software one at a time and go through all of the uninstall prompts.

I am looking for a program that:

- Automatically uninstalls multiple programs one right after the other
- Works with Windows 7/8/8.1
- Could do silent uninstalls of all the programs so I don't have to click through a bunch of uninstall prompts
- *Could save an uninstall selection to be ran on another computer without needing to select the same software again*
- Is free or relatively cheap

Comment: (Saving an uninstall selection cannot be done in Revo Uninstaller Pro, which would have been my best guess)

Comment: as an answer already suggests, wouldn't it be MUCH easier to just make a SO image once it is just as you want it, and then just to deploy such image to every machine. I worked on a company that made this, they had preconfigured SO's and just installed them on every machine in a matter of minutes. However, I am not sure exactly what SW they use (I barely remember it was something from Acronis) and how they managed the OS licences issue (i guess it was a unique corporate licence)

Comment: update, I found this, which seems to be exactly what you need: [Acronis Snap Deploy](http://www.acronis.com/es-mx/business/enterprise-solutions/image-deployment-new/)

Answer (score 1):

The right answer is cloning!!
Make an image for each OS 7 and 8.1.  (8.1 is free upgrade to 8 so just do it)

Take 1  Windows 7 PC and do all your steps.

Take 1  Windows 8.1 PC and do all your steps.

Take a spare computer, and download and burn drbl from drbl.sourceforge.net to CD or USB stick

Capture both as separate image.  win7 and win8.1  (masters)

run as Administrator  c:\windows\system32\sysprep /generalize /oobe

(on both)

recapture as win7-go and win8-go

Use a cheap netgear and drbl to multicast images to 7,15,23 computers at once.
You should be able to do a batch in <15mins

Change the product key enter basic data and the PC is done.

If you are interested leave me a comment and I can get more detailed instruction.  Depending on the number of ports on the netgear you should be able to churn out 7,15, or 23 computers every 30 minutes or so.

Answer (score 0):

Evil/Lame way, but what you say you want:

go here:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall

Find all 15 apps by **DisplayName** and then locate there **UninstallString** key.

**If you get really lucky** there will be a **SilentUninstallString** or **QuietUninstallString** value

Copy and paste all 15 **UninstallString** into **Notepad**

You may have to locate additional switches to silence the uninstallers, and some may not be silence-able at all.

**Save as** remove-evil.bat  change file type to **All**

Click save

copy and paste onto each PC and right click and **Run as Administrator**

spend time locating the final switches to make them silent.

Answer (score 0):

**CCleaner** might be what you're looking for.

It has all the installed programs, click one and press Run Uninstaller and done:
It also has a Cleaner, which removes unnecessary files, a Registry section which fixes small problems on your PC and more.

Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CCleaner

Website: http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner

[image: Screenshot of the uninstall screen]

Comment: It can't uninstall multiple programs at once or in a sequence.